# how can I convert a text to float in python?

Tags: python-3.5

I will import exchange rate from a site and I will use exchange rate to calculate.I have no problem about importing.But I will import exchange rate as string.I must convert string to float to calculate.But I couldn't.I don't know where problem is.Section of Show some code is just a instance.It has same problem.

I will use data for calculation with exchange rate.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.bloomberght.com"
response = requests.get(url)
icerik = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(icerik, "html.parser")
liste = []
liste2=[]
for i in soup.find_all("div", {"class", "line2"}):
    i =i.text
    liste.append(i.strip())

A=8*float(liste[2])
print(A)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/proin/PycharmProjects/software222/BBBBBBB.py", line 15, in 
    A=8*float(liste[2])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '6,5827'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.replace()` to replace `,` to `.`. Then the conversion to float will work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.bloomberght.com"
response = requests.get(url)
icerik = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(icerik, "html.parser")
liste = []
liste2= []
for i in soup.find_all("div", {"class", "line2"}):
    i = i.text
    liste.append(i.strip().replace(',', '.'))

A=8*float(liste[2])
print(A)
```

Prints:

```
52.6456
```